# How to access a PHP Web Service from ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wsdl

I am trying use a web service in a C# ASP.Net Web Application. The service is built in PHP  and is located on some remote server not under my control so I cant modify it to add meta data or something else into it.

When I use the "Add Web Reference" option in Visual Studio 2008,
I receive the following error:

> The HTML document does not contain Web
>   service discovery information.

while trying to add the following web service.

https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php?wsdl

The web service functions are exposed and displayed in Visual Studio 2008. however i could not add the reference to it for use in ASP.Net Application.

> t3Service" Description
>
> Methods
>   __construct ( )
>
> create_contact ( )
>
> get_contact ( )
>
> get_domain_info ( )
>
> get_last_error_code ( )
>
> get_last_error_msg ( )
>
> get_NSSET ( )
>
> get_owner_mail ( )
>
> login ( )
>
> register_domain ( )
>
> register_domain_with_admin_contacts (
>   )
>
> renew_domain ( )
>
> request_sendmail ( )
>
> send_auth_info ( )
>
> transfer_domain ( )

2. I also tried the wsdl.exe method by retrieving the xml and copying it to a wsdl file and generating a proxy class. But the wsdl output contains warnings and the proxy class generated skips the exposed functions and generates something like this:

   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'create_contact' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'get_contact' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'get_domain_info' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'get_last_error_code' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'get_last_error_msg' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'get_NSSET' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'get_owner_mail' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'send_auth_info' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'transfer_domain' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'request_sendmail' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'login' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'register_domain' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'register_domain_with_admin_contacts' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.
   // CODEGEN: The operation binding 'renew_domain' from namespace 'urn:t3' was ignored.  Each message part in an use=encoded message must specify a type.

Edit:

I tried this piece of code for my hand coded class.

```
public String makeWebRequest(String methodName)
        {
              // Create the web request  
              HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php/") as HttpWebRequest;  
              // Add authentication to request  
              request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("foo@mydomain.com", "bar");
              request.Method = "POST";
              request.ContentType = "text/xml";
              request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php/" + methodName);

            // Get response  
          using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)  
             {  
               // Get the response stream  
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  
               // Console application output  
               //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
               return reader.ReadToEnd();
             }  
        }
```

But when I try to get response then it returns

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As referenced that - you will have to hand code your "proxy" for this web service.

One example of manually making a web service call - you may have to tweak the method some.

```
private string MakeWebServiceCall(string methodName, string requestXmlString)
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php");

            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php/" + methodName);
            Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();

            //Create Stream and Complete Request
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
            streamWriter.Write(String.Format(this.GetSoapString(), requestXmlString));
            streamWriter.Close();

            //Get the Response
            WebResponse webResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            //Read the response into an xml document
            System.Xml.XmlDocument soapResonseXMLDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            soapResonseXMLDocument.LoadXml(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

            //return only the xml representing the response details (inner request)
            return soapResonseXMLDocument.GetElementsByTagName(methodName + "Result")[0].InnerXml;
        }
```

I would recommend creating xsd's which can be used to generate objects (using xsd.exe) and then you can serialized/deserialize responses and requests to actually objects.

EDIT:
GetSoapString() method

```
private string GetSoapString()
        {
            StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
            soapRequest.Append(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ");
            soapRequest.Append("xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body>");
            soapRequest.Append("{0}");
            soapRequest.Append("</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
            return soapRequest.ToString();
        }
```

For Steve's Reference

Call one looks like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<get_contact>
<id>123</id>
</get_contact>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:t3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:get_contactResponse>
         <get_contactReturn xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</get_contactReturn>
      </ns1:get_contactResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: @Dan Thanks a lot for this piece of code. It really cleared my thinking abt the issue. 

Every thing is quite understandable in your code. But i couldnt get/find the function named *GetSoapString*. Can you please just tell what it does so that i could write one of my own or if it is already defined then could you give it implementation or .Net Namespace that conatins the definition for it???

Comment: @Dan
I did try your code. But when try to get a Response from server i receive the following:

*The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.*

Is it normal? If yes then what i need to do in my code to process such a response.

Before posting my problem at stackoverflow, i tried some other code and tried to send a web request but the same error was returned.

Does it mean that it requires some Authorization or credetials? I clearly see a Login() function there? Is it the SSL thatis creating the problem? If i am to send credentials to the web service how to send them?

Comment: @Dan

* WebResponse webResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse(); *

This is the line where the error above is returned..

Comment: Steve, I'm sorry I forgot to include the GetSoapString - this is one of those utility functions I keep in my bag for the times I have to manually create proxy code.

Typically an error 500 comes from a bad header when attempting to make webservice calls...I'll look at that really quick.

Comment: @Steve - I tested this code above and with everything I provided your call should work perfectly. Note: in the last line of the method MakeWebServiceCall the php webservice actually returns a node called methodname+"Response" not methodname+"Result".

Comment: @Dan 
Thanks a lot for your help. It worked like a charm. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"webservice" is a very generic term. Some types of webservice may implement a WSDL - but its not a requirement. IIRC a SOAP interface is required to provide a WSDL, and both nuSOAP and the PHP SOAP extension support WSDL. So it looks like the remote end hasn't been implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
**Previously i got a 500 Internal server error because my soap string was not correctly formatted. I ananlyzed the xml being returned from the web service and built my soap string message by look at xml.
Finally i got over the problem with help from *Dan* ^ & some bit of research over the internet. Thanks Dan.**

> I got over the 500 server error. Now i
>   am able to get a response of login
>   failure atleast...

```
public String MyWebServiceCall()
        {
            string strSoapMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
            + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:tns=\"http://www.artwork-systems.com/webway/sessions\" xmlns:types=\"http://www.artwork-systems.com/webway/sessions/encodedTypes\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
            + " <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
            + " <tns:Login>"
            + " <login xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Support@foo.net</login>"
            + " <auth xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">bar</auth>"
            + " </tns:Login>"
            + " </soap:Body>"
            + "</soap:Envelope>";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(@"https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php/"));

            req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Accept = "text/xml";
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", @"https://subreg.forpsi.com/robot2/subreg_command.php/");
            req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Support@foo.net", "bar");

            StreamWriter stm = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            stm.Write(strSoapMessage);
            stm.Flush();
            stm.Close();

            HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
            string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
            return resulXmlFromWebService;
        }
```

Now the next problem is to pass the correct credentials and process the response to do other stuff...

btw, here was the response....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:t3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:loginResponse><loginReturn xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</loginReturn></ns1:loginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Edit:
**The value false is Ok as i am sending in the wrong credentials. i call other functions of the web service in a similar fashion and was able to call all functions of the web service and retrieve the corresponding return values and then perform other processing.**

Thanks all who helped contributing  to solve the problem.

Regards