# How to add web reference to script component in SSIS

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ssis, etl

I have a package in SSIS and i need to retrieve some data from a web service. I can not use the web service task because the name of the service has spaces and then I dont know why its not possible with this kind of web services. So I went with the script component as source. My idea is to consume the web service from that script using c sharp. I add the web reference and the script compiles fine. 
The problem is that after I close the script editor, the script component throws an error. When I try to execute the package shows as the image below.

[image: error code]

I am using Visual studio 2010. I am sure the problem is with the web reference because when i remove it, the error goes away.

Any workarounds, help??

**Edit 1**

This is the error better seen

[image: error code]

None of PrecompileiIntoBindaryCode nor DelayValidation properties appear on the Properties panel of the Script component.

**Edit 2**
I ended up consuming the web service dinammicaly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469594/how-to-access-a-php-web-service-from-asp-net) it is the post that saved my life.

Also I used the program SOAPUI to know the xml request to the web service.

Comment: Could you please add error message as a part of question,it's really difficult read it from screen shoot!

Answer (score 0):

The error message usually means validation has failed; in most cases due to outdated metadata or metadata isn't updated with the recent changes. Looks like the schema has been updated for web service reference. Try setting `ValidateExternalMetadata` to `False`

The `VS_ISBROKEN` Message is last of the validation errors and there was another ballistic message that appeared before this - `The binary code for the script is not found`

Sometimes any error in code may lead to this error.Open up the script. Make sure there are no errors. Close it again and click OK.If you are certain that the code is correct you can go to the script properties and set the `PrecompileiIntoBindaryCode` to `False`, the default is set to true.  This is under the Properties or in the Script option of the properties window. Or `DelayValidation` property, needs to be set to '`TRUE`'.

MSDN Documentation:

> In SQL Server 2008 Integration Services (SSIS) and later versions, all
>   scripts are precompiled. In previous versions, you specified whether
>   scripts were precompiled by setting a Precompile property for the
>   task.
>
> Unlike earlier versions where you could indicate whether the scripts
>   were precompiled, all scripts are precompiled in SQL Server 2008
>   Integration Services (SSIS). When a script is precompiled, the
>   language engine is not loaded at run time and the package runs more
>   quickly. However, precompiled binary files consume significant disk
>   space.

- [Configuring the Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135927.aspx)